# Apache CXF + SpringBoot: Can I publish multiple endpoints for one SOAP web-service?

Tags: web-services, spring-boot, soap, cxf

I have implemented a SOAP Webservice using Apache CXF + SpringBoot.

In my Endpoint Configuration class, I have

```
@Bean
public Endpoint endpoint()
{
    EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(cxfBus, new ServiceImpl());
    endpoint.publish("/myservice");
    return endpoint;
}
```

This creates a web-service endpoint as https://host:port/myService

To this service I need to expose multiple endpoints - something like -
https://host:port/tenant1/myService
https://host:port/tenant2/myService
https://host:port/tenant3/myService

This is kind of REST endpoint -- i.e, I am trying to pass the tenantId variable in the service endpoint.

Is this possible in Apache CXF + Springboot ?

I tried this -

```
@Bean
public Endpoint endpoint()
{
    EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(cxfBus, new ServiceImpl()); 
    String[] pathArray = {"tenant1", "tenant2", "tenant3"};
    for (int i = 0; i < pathArray.length; i++)
    {
        endpoint.publish("/" + pathArray[i] + "/myservice");
    }
    return endpoint;
}
```

But it does not work.

I would really appreciate any inputs/suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Which solution did you implement ? Because I have to create multiple endpoint s dynamically from a list of urls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you can not have same endpoint mapped to multiple urls, One Endpoint is create for  a wsdl file which that would be generated to single class. From the urls I assume you want to host same service on multiple url based on tenant. In that case you have to create endpoints for each tenant.

```
@Bean
public Endpoint endpoint1()
{
    EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(cxfBus, new ServiceImpl()); 
    endpoint.publish("/tenant1/" + pathArray[i] + "/myservice");
    return endpoint;
}

@Bean
public Endpoint endpoint2()
{
    EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(cxfBus, new ServiceImpl()); 
    endpoint.publish("/tenant1/" + pathArray[i] + "/myservice");
    return endpoint;
}
```

**OR**

```
@Configuration
public class CxfConfiguration implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory factory) throws BeansException {

        Arrays.stream(new String[] { "tenant1", "tenant2" }).forEach(str -> {
            Bus bus = factory.getBean(Bus.class);
            JaxWsServerFactoryBean bean = new JaxWsServerFactoryBean();
            bean.setAddress("/" + str + "/myService");
            bean.setBus(bus);
            bean.setServiceClass(HelloWorld.class);
            factory.registerSingleton(str, bean.create());
        });

    }


}
```

BTW: May be better way use REST?